# Hibernate two level cascade not working with explicit clearing of Set

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
public class Base {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Order> orders;
}

public class Order {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Product> products;
}

public class Product {

  //fields
}
```

When trying to update Base with updated products ( removing product from one of the Order), I am getting A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.xx.yy.zz.Order.products

Before `saveAndFlush(base)`, I am clearing the data as well.

```
base.getOrders().forEach(order -> order.getProducts().clear());
base.getOrders().clear();
base.getOrders().addAll(baseToUpdate.getOrders());
```

How do I make sure that products are cleared before adding the new orders?